# read elements from json array in playframework scala

Tags: scala, play-json

Given a json:

```scala
val json = """
{
  "persons": [
    {"name": "Foo", "age": 21},    
    {"name": "Bar", "age": 22},
    {"name": "Baz", "age": 23}
  ]
}
"""
```

How to construct a play `Reads[List[String]]` which will extract list of names form that json?

```scala
import play.api.libs.json._

val reads: Reads[List[String]] = ???

val names: List[String] = reads.reads(Json.parse(json)) 
// expecting List("Foo", "Bar", "Baz")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just compose with `Reads`.

```scala
import play.api.libs.json._

val input = Json.parse("""
{
  "persons": [
    {"name": "Foo", "age": 21},    
    {"name": "Bar", "age": 22},
    {"name": "Baz", "age": 23}
  ]
}
""")

val nameReads = (JsPath \ "name").read[String]
val listReads: Reads[Seq[String]] = Reads.seq(nameReads)

(input \ "persons").validate(listReads)
// JsSuccess(Vector(Foo, Bar, Baz),)
```

Comment: Actually the question was `How to construct a play Reads[List[String]]`. My edit to your response provided this information, shame that you have rejected it...

Answer (score 3):

Could try the workaround?

```
final case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
object Person {
  implicit val PersonFormat = Json.format[Person]
}


val jsonStr= """
{
  "persons": [
    {"name": "Foo", "age": 21},
    {"name": "Bar", "age": 22},
    {"name": "Baz", "age": 23}
  ]
}
"""

(Json.parse(jsonStr) \ "persons").as[List[Person]].map(p => p.name)
```

Or

```
((Json.parse(jsonStr) \ "persons") \\ "name").map(_.as[String])
```

Comment: If for easy:
((Json.parse(jsonStr) \ "persons") \\ "name").map(_.as[String]) .    that is ok

Comment: The goal is to define a `Reads`, not a `JsResult` + `.as[T]` is unsafe

Comment: This is a good approach it worked fine to me.